# How to retrieve the CPU and Memory Usage at the container level by using the Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes

I got the CPU and Memory Usage of my application container and splunk container by using the following command: `kubectl top pod --containers -n default`

```
POD                       NAME              CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
abc-6cbf8f544c-g72b6      main                 1m           479Mi
abc-6cbf8f544c-g72b6      splunkforwarder      3m           150Mi
```

Requirement: I need to retrieve the CPU and Memory usage of container level of my application container (container name= main) into the splunk logs

Below is my current python code:

```
import os
import logging
from logging import INFO, DEBUG, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL
from kubernetes import client, config
import psutil

if "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST" in os.environ and "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT" in os.environ:
   \# Load cluster config from within the pod
   config.load_incluster_config()

#This code is getting all the host level usage.
def get_cpu_memory_usage():
    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent()
    memory_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
    return cpu_percent, memory_usage

def get_container_metrics(container_name):
    api = client.CustomObjectsApi()
    group = "metrics.k8s.io"
    version = "v1beta1"
    plural = "pods"

    pod_name = os.environ.get('POD_NAME')
    pod_namespace = os.environ.get('POD_NAMESPACE')

    print(f"Namespace: {pod_namespace}")

    response = api.list_namespaced_custom_object(
        group, version, namespace=pod_namespace, plural=plural
    )
    for item in response["items"]:
        metadata = item.get("metadata", {})
        containers = item.get("containers", [])
        for container in containers:
            if container["name"] == container_name:
                cpu_usage = container["usage"]["cpu"]
                memory_usage = container["usage"]["memory"]
                return cpu_usage, memory_usage
    print(f"Container '{container_name}' not found in pod '{pod_name}'")
    return None, None


def get_pod_status():
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    pod_name = os.environ.get('POD_NAME')
    pod_namespace = os.environ.get('POD_NAMESPACE')
    pod = v1.read_namespaced_pod(pod_name, pod_namespace)
    pod_status = pod.status.phase
    return pod_status
```

Please correct the code to get the accurate data of the CPU and Memory Usage of my container(main)

I tried with the mentioned code and I'm getting the below error:

> Error Message:
> Error fetching container metrics: Missing the required parameter `namespace` when calling `list_namespaced_custom_object`
> Failed to retrieve container metrics.

Comment: Can you access `POD_NAME` and `POD_NAMESPACE` variables from your python script?

Comment: Yes, @MarcinOrlowski I'm able to access the POD_NAME and POD_NAMESPACE as in the deployment.yaml file I have given the below parameters:

- name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace

and also gave Role and Rolebinding access in the yaml file. After doing these changes I'm able to access the PODNAME and PODNAMESPACE